# Set Index of Array (SwiftUI)

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing, swiftui, picker

I am working through hackingwithswift doing the 100 Days of SwiftUI and currently on Day 35 which needs me to build a times table app.

Unfortunately, I have got stuck at a very early stage and feel stupid asking.

How can I make my array index start at 1 rather than 0?

Below is my code and screenshot of the canvas:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var number = 0
    @State private var question = Int.random(in: 0..<13)

    let numberRange = Array<Int>(1 ... 12)

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("What times tables do you want to test your knowledge on?", selection: $number) {
                ForEach(0 ..< numberRange.count) {
                    Text("\(self.numberRange[$0])")
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

            Text("What is \(number) x \(question) = ")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: SwiftUI Canvas]

Comment: Could you please tell us a little bit more about the use case this is needed? What is your goal. Why does the array need to start at 1?

Comment: I was thinking having an array for the user to pick the multiplication table they wanted to play
Thought this would be a good way of achinging that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple documentation:

> The first element of a nonempty array is always at index zero.

Basically you'd need to add +1 to your `number` variable.

```
var correctNumber: Int {
    number + 1
}
```

And use this `correctNumber` when displaying values or performing calculations.

```
Text("What is \(correctNumber) x \(question)?")
```

As `correctNumber` is a computed property it will always be up to date with `number` variable.

Comment: Thank you, this has worked.  Knew it was going to be stupidly obvious